# Como remover a mensagem 'Invalid username or password, try again' da página de login do CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp, login

Eu comecei a usar o [cakephp](/questions/tagged/cakephp) recentemente e criei uma página de *login* para o meu projeto. O *login* funciona perfeitamente, mas está sempre exibindo uma mensagem de usuário ou senha inválidos.

O que eu posso fazer para exibir esta mensagem APENAS quando o *login* for inválido?

### Função de *login*:

```
public function login() {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            if($this->Auth->user('role') === 'paciente') {
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pacientes', 'action' => 'index'));
            }
            elseif($this->Auth->user('role') === 'medico') {
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'medicos', 'action' => 'index'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode verificar se a requisição da página é um `post` com o `$this->request->is('post');`

```
public function login() {
    if($this->request->is('post')){
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            if($this->Auth->user('role') === 'paciente') {
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'pacientes', 'action' => 'index'));
            }
            elseif($this->Auth->user('role') === 'medico') {
                $this->redirect(array('controller' => 'medicos', 'action' => 'index'));
            }
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }

}
```

Referência da documentação [neste link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/pt/controllers/request-response.html#inspecionando-a-requisicao)